# Dynamic linking Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic-linking

I'm looking for a way of dynamic linking.

Outline is:

Lets have an app with many data filters that have all the same outlines (function names, internally used datatypes, some exported datatypes of single class).

It would be great for me to check present .so files, load only those needed, based on command line arguments, and run then.
I dont want to change or recompile app everytime new module is added.

Is something like this possible today?

Tried some hacking with `System.Plugins`, failed every time. Sometimes one hate strong typechecking.

EDIT

If I wrote something like this directly and gave him type hint on calling makeChunks, it is ok, otherwise nothing

```
--SharedClass --should create common interface
class (Eq c, Show c) => Chunks c where
    makeChunks :: String -> [c]

--Plugin --one concrete implementation
import SharedClass
data MyChunk = SmallChunk Char deriving (Eq) 
instance Chunks MyChunk where
    makeChunks _ = [SmallChunk 's']
instance Show MyChunk where
    show (SmallChunk s) = [s]

--main
import SharedClass
    --load plugin somehow
print $ makeChunks "abcd"
```

Comment: Should be possible.  Maybe post the code you've tried?

Comment: @JohnL Never actualy finished compilation of main app, Always ambiguous types on that crucial function.

Comment: It is an ambiguous type.  `makeChunks "abcd" :: Chunks c => [c]`, and `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`.  The compiler doesn't know which type to use for `c` unless you add a type annotation somewhere.  In general, class constraints don't affect type inferencing.  In other words, even though there's only one instance of `Chunks` in scope, the compiler won't automatically choose that type.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But I do not see, how can I achieve disambiguity with this sort of plugin setup. I can do this staticaly writing every posibility for few instances, not for few dozens. This thing I am proposing look much like abstract classes or interfaces from classbased languages. Is it doable?

Comment: Perhaps rather than defining a _class_ and making each plugin define one instance of that class, what you actually want is for each plugin to expose a _function_ value that does what you want...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Would I be able to channel data from one plugin to another through main application logic, given that both these modules use same datatype definitions, but main application doesn't know them specificaly?

Comment: @user978734: It's possible, but it requires some slightly non-standard types.  You might want to look at `Data.Dynamic` for one approach.